# getConfig function run time

Tags: magento-1.9, core, getmodel

I measured run time for my page and noticed that the function getBaseCurrencyCode() takes over a second to run. All of my caching are enabled.

I examined the function and saw that the following command:

```
$this->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE)
```

takes over a second.

but when I use the  `Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE);` 
it takes milliseconds

can anyone tell me why is this time difference occurs ?

any advice?

---

Although I’ve tried the suggested solutions you offered but still there are massive time gaps.  I would be happy if you can try and measure the time it takes for you to run the getConfig function and post it here.

I tried measure the time this function takes by wrapping this code with microtime functions

i.e  on local path : `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model`
instead of this line :

```
$configValue = $this->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE);
```

I replaced it with this code (same code with microtime):

```
$start = microtime(true);

$configValue = $this->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE);

$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "function: getConfig() took me: " .  $time_elapsed_secs . " sec<br />";

die;
```

my output was:

```
function: getConfig() took me: 1.1326711177826 sec
```

I would be happy to see your output and runtime.

Answer (score 4):

There are small differences in parsing the config between the 2 but those should not affect performance. Both of the methods just go through a big array to retrieve data.
`getConfig` actually does some simple calculations and then calls `getNode`.
The only big difference I see is that `$this->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE)` calls this: `$this->_processConfigValue($fullPath, $path, $data);`.
This part processes directives marked with `{{...}}` and at some point the method calls it self under certain circumstances.
Try to benchmark the 2 after you remove the `_processConfigValue` call.

Answer (score 3):

When you call

```
$this->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE)
```

It will call

```
 public function getConfig($path)
    {
        if (isset($this->_configCache[$path])) {
            return $this->_configCache[$path];
        }

        $config = Mage::getConfig();

        $fullPath = 'stores/' . $this->getCode() . '/' . $path;
        $data = $config->getNode($fullPath);
        if (!$data && !Mage::isInstalled()) {
            $data = $config->getNode('default/' . $path);
        }
        if (!$data) {
            return null;
        }
        return $this->_processConfigValue($fullPath, $path, $data);
    }
```

also

```
protected function _processConfigValue($fullPath, $path, $node)
    {
        if (isset($this->_configCache[$path])) {
            return $this->_configCache[$path];
        }

        if ($node->hasChildren()) {
            $aValue = array();
            foreach ($node->children() as $k => $v) {
                $aValue[$k] = $this->_processConfigValue($fullPath . '/' . $k, $path . '/' . $k, $v);
            }
            $this->_configCache[$path] = $aValue;
            return $aValue;
        }

        $sValue = (string) $node;
        if (!empty($node['backend_model']) && !empty($sValue)) {
            $backend = Mage::getModel((string) $node['backend_model']);
            $backend->setPath($path)->setValue($sValue)->afterLoad();
            $sValue = $backend->getValue();
        }

        if (is_string($sValue) && strpos($sValue, '{{') !== false) {
            if (strpos($sValue, '{{unsecure_base_url}}') !== false) {
                $unsecureBaseUrl = $this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL);
                $sValue = str_replace('{{unsecure_base_url}}', $unsecureBaseUrl, $sValue);
            } elseif (strpos($sValue, '{{secure_base_url}}') !== false) {
                $secureBaseUrl = $this->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL);
                $sValue = str_replace('{{secure_base_url}}', $secureBaseUrl, $sValue);
            } elseif (strpos($sValue, '{{base_url}}') !== false) {
                $sValue = Mage::getConfig()->substDistroServerVars($sValue);
            }
        }

        $this->_configCache[$path] = $sValue;

        return $sValue;
    }
```

and when you call

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE)
```

It will read `xml` file and return output.

I think As per [@Marius sir](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) suggest and it wont affect performance.